# How to run a perl script using PBS on a HPC cluster?

Tags: perl, hpc, pbs

I am struggling with running perl script which needs several required modules (perl modules). The only way I can submit this job is through:

```
qsub my_code.pbs
```

Directly submitted shell commands are not allowed by root admin.
perl is present by default as version 5.10 but I may need perl 5.16 or above and have no root privileges. I know so far that PBS scripts expects any program to be loaded as a PBS module
This is what I tried using mpirun

```
#!/bin/csh
#PBS -l walltime=10:00:00
#PBS -N hello_world1
#PBS -q workq
#PBS -l select=4:ncpus=16:mpiprocs=16
#PBS -l place=scatter:excl
#PBS -V

module load "/usr/bin/perl"
cmd="perl t2.pl"
mpirun -np 2 $cmd
# Go to the directory from which you submitted the job
echo PBS working directory is $PBS_O_WORKDIR
# echo PBS default server is $PBS_DEFAULT
echo $PBS_NODEFILE
```

I am not sure if I should directly include this

```
perl t2.pl
```

instead of mpirun.
perl is not listed in available modules. Even if I get it done by requesting the root admin, I am still unsure if the required *perl modules* shall work or not?

My perl code requires:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use List::Util qw( sum );
use YAML;
```

> Note:   Perl module is the cpan modules that I use and call inside perl code.
>   PBS Module refers to software modules loaded via module script on HPC cluster.

Comment: I don't think this is correct `$module load "/usr/bin/perl"`

Comment: Can you see Perl if you do `perl --version`?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::MPI::Simple

Comment: Let's learn to crawl before we try to run. Can you get a perl script that writes "Hello world" to standard output or to a file working? How about a script that writes "Hello world" and loads one or more of your desired modules? It's way too early to bother your admin.

Comment: I'd suggest to first find detailed examples of how to use the local `qsub` (unless what you show follows one of those). Admins normally post them. Then go as mob says, step at a time.  Once you are sure it's all working check with your admin whether it's OK to run threads there; also, be very careful how you use them, lest you overload the system.

Comment: @Tung I requested admin to install higher perl version as module=perl5.16.3 with required perl modules installed. Now I simply need to 'load module perl5.16.3' and then regular perl command 'perl code.pl'
The perl module Threads ran the code using multiple threads.

Comment: @mob The code runs fine but no file gets created in write mode that I tried inside perl code. 'open FOUT, ">file.txt";' did not create any file. but the output can be printed to pbs output file or terminal. Why is that happening ?

Comment: What directory do you think the remote script is trying to create the `file.txt` file in? Try writing to `/path/visible/on/local/machinefile.txt`